# how to run passenger automatically when ubuntu server starts

Tags: ubuntu, passenger

Hi I want to run passenger automatically when I turn on the Ubuntu server. I'm new to this concept. I tried in google. but I did not get anything. please share your ideas here

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to run when a user logs in, put an entry in .bashrc in the home directory.

The easiest way is with an editor like 'nano' or 'vi', but if you don't have time to learn them, you could do this:

```
cd ~
echo "passenger" >> .bash.rc
```

Comment: Do you knw how to put entry in .bashrc?

Comment: I put my answer above.